# C++ - No matching function call with clang, works with gcc

Tags: c++, clang

Take a look at the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

class Stream
{
  public:
    template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>{} || std::is_enum<T>{}>>
    Stream& append(T value)
    {
        this->m_str.append(std::to_string(value));
        return *this;
    }

    Stream& append(std::string value)
    {
        this->m_str.append(value);
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename T>
    Stream& operator<<(T value)
    {
        return this->append(value);
    }

    std::string& str()
    {
        return this->m_str;   
    }

  private:
    std::string m_str;
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<bool> vec = {true, true, false};
    Stream stream;
    for (auto it = vec.cbegin(); it != vec.cend(); ++it)
    {
        stream << *it;
    }
    stream << "test" << 12;
    std::cout << stream.str() << std::endl;
}
```

This works when compiling with gcc but not with clang3.8+.

Clang can't seem to find a matching function:

```
source_file.cpp:25:22: error: no matching member function for call to 'append'
        return this->append(value);
               ~~~~~~^~~~~~
```

The problem occurs in the loop when trying to dereference the iterator and insert the bools into the stream.
Why is it working with gcc but not with clang?

Comment: `vector<bool>` is weird. `*it` may (at the implementation's discretion) be an instance of a proxy class that knows how to access an individual bit inside; as opposed to a `bool&`. Neither of the two `append` overloads can take this proxy class. Looks like the standard library implementation that comes with GCC doesn't attempt to implement `vector<bool>` as a bit sequence, while the one that comes with clang does.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That would be true if `it` were a `std::vector<bool>::iterator`, but it's a `const_iterator`, and `std::vector<bool>::const_reference` is required to be just `bool`.

Comment: @aschepler If that's the case (I haven't checked), then [clang is non-conforming](http://rextester.com/WCDW70781) . There, the type of `*it`is something that `typeid` believes to be named `NSt3__121__bit_const_referenceINS_6vectorIbNS_9allocatorIbEEEEEE`

Comment: Maybe the difference is actually in standard library implementations?

Comment: Although I don't see any requirement that the `reference` or `const_reference` type of a container's iterator matches the container's member, just requirements on their value types.

Comment: @aschepler Came here to say that. I, too, went looking and couldn't find a requirement that `*a.begin()` be of type `X::reference` or `X::const_reference`. The latter are only used for direct element access - `operator[]`, `at()`, `front()`, `back()`

Comment: Ok but which behavior is defined?

Comment: @Saruman My reading is that both compilers are correct. The standard leaves a lot of `vector<bool>` implementation-defined, and you have a program that depends on implementation details.